What's the best way to parallelize python loop which uses Spotipy to pull track data from Spotfiy's database?
I'm using the below code to input a uri, a unique identifier for a song on Spotify, and receive the data for that song from Spotify's API. df is the dataframe containing all uris under column x.
def get_features(any_uri):
    track=sp.track(any_uri)
    artist_info=track['album']['artists'][0]
    artist_name.append(artist_info['name'])
    album_name.append(sp.track(uri)['album']['name'])
    track_name.append(sp.track(uri)['name'])
    track_id.append(sp.track(uri)['id'])
    release_date.append(sp.track(uri)['album']['release_date'])
    t=sp.audio_features(uri)[0]
    danceability.append(t['danceability'])
    energy.append(t['energy'])
    key.append(t['key'])
    loudness.append(t['loudness'])
    mode.append(t['mode'])
    speechiness.append(t['speechiness'])
    acousticness.append(t['acousticness'])
    instrumentalness.append(t['instrumentalness'])
    liveness.append(t['liveness'])
    valence.append(t['valence'])
    tempo.append(t['tempo'])
    track_href.append(t['track_href'])
    analysis_url.append(t['analysis_url'])
    duration_ms.append(t['duration_ms'])
    time_signature.append(t['time_signature'])


for i in range(0,n,1):
    uri=df.at[i,"x"]
    get_features(uri)

Another stack overflow post suggested asyncio, so I tried implementing this (see below)
import asyncio

def background(f):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        return asyncio.get_event_loop().run_in_executor(None, f, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapped

@background
def get_features(any_uri):
    track=sp.track(any_uri)
    artist_info=track['album']['artists'][0]
    artist_name.append(artist_info['name'])
    album_name.append(sp.track(uri)['album']['name'])
    track_name.append(sp.track(uri)['name'])
    track_id.append(sp.track(uri)['id'])
    release_date.append(sp.track(uri)['album']['release_date'])
    t=sp.audio_features(uri)[0]
    danceability.append(t['danceability'])
    energy.append(t['energy'])
    key.append(t['key'])
    loudness.append(t['loudness'])
    mode.append(t['mode'])
    speechiness.append(t['speechiness'])
    acousticness.append(t['acousticness'])
    instrumentalness.append(t['instrumentalness'])
    liveness.append(t['liveness'])
    valence.append(t['valence'])
    tempo.append(t['tempo'])
    track_href.append(t['track_href'])
    analysis_url.append(t['analysis_url'])
    duration_ms.append(t['duration_ms'])
    time_signature.append(t['time_signature'])


for i in range(0,n,1):
    uri=df.at[i,"x"]
    get_features(uri)

But this is only outputting 8 songs, 7 of which are identical.
['2yKNCN7jsi5XtwJL5jBG1z',
 '0MBRKCgePXewM1iBQiPn7Q',
 '0MBRKCgePXewM1iBQiPn7Q',
 '0MBRKCgePXewM1iBQiPn7Q',
 '0MBRKCgePXewM1iBQiPn7Q',
 '0MBRKCgePXewM1iBQiPn7Q',
 '0MBRKCgePXewM1iBQiPn7Q',
 '0MBRKCgePXewM1iBQiPn7Q']

I was never very good at parallel programming, so I'm sure I'm just not understanding something here. Any guidance is appreciated!
